# Vue.js router-link doesn't work on firefox

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have this button component:

```
    <button :class="classes" v-on="$listeners" v-bind="$attrs">
    <template v-if="to">
      <router-link :to="to" class="flex center-v">
        <AqIcon :icon="icon" v-if="icon" />
        <slot></slot>
      </router-link>

    </template>
    <template v-else>
      <AqIcon :icon="icon" v-if="icon" />
      <slot></slot>
    </template>

  </button>
```

It can accepts a `:to` prop and in that case I use a router-link instead of just text.

When I use it like this:

```
<AqButton primary icon="plus" :to="{name:'editUser',params:{id:'new'}}">
     Add User
</AqButton>
```

On chrome it works fine, but on FF the url changes but it stays on the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently, it doesn't work if you nest the router link under a button element.

So i changed my component to look like this:

```
<template>
  <router-link v-if="to" :to="to" :class="classes" v-on="$listeners" v-bind="$attrs">
    <AqIcon :icon="icon" v-if="icon" />
    <slot></slot>
  </router-link>

  <button v-else :class="classes" v-on="$listeners" v-bind="$attrs">
    <AqIcon :icon="icon" v-if="icon" />
    <slot></slot>
  </button>

</template>
```

And now it works.